# Consecutive One's and Identities, resulting on Totally Unimodular Matrix...

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, integer-programming, total-unimodularity

I'm trying to prove that a linear problem has integer extreme points. Looking at the matrix structures, I guess the easiest way to prove this is by showing that this matrix is totally unimodular. My matrix (and its structutes) can be described as follows.

\begin{equation}B=
\begin{pmatrix}
 I & A &0\\
 I & 0 & A
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Such that matrix $A\in R^{m\times n}$ has the consecutive ones property and, thus, is totally unimodular. Can I show that matrix $B$ is also totally unimodular?

Comment: is the C1P row-wise or column-wise?

Comment: The consecutive one's from A are row-wise.

Comment: Counterexamples can be found for both cases. I have added one to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed the counter-example works... Since TUM does not apply, I'll try to see if I can manage to solve my issue with TDI-ness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
 A &0\\
 0 & A
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

also has the consecutive ones property and is TUM. It remains TUM if you append one large identity matrix, but you add two smaller identity matrices, which can ruin TUM. Just generating random matrices $A$ quickly results in counterexamples, for example
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
The submatrix of rows 1,3,5,6,10 and columns 1,5,7,10,13 has determinant 2.

Comment: Hi LinAlg, thanks for your answer! Yes, that's the thing I want to figure out...Eventually, even extending it to more than 2 repetitions of matrices A and I... I'm pretty sure it remains TUM but haven't manage to proof it yet...